Given the total cost of many graph walks, how to estimate the cost of each edge?
I have a real-world problem in which I have a collection of nodes and their edges. This collection is composed of hundreds of nodes and thousands of connections. Then I have about 10 K datapoints each representing a path taken in this graph and the total cost of each path(the sum of the cost of edges travelled through in each path). I'm looking for a function that given the paths estimates the costs for each of the edges.
The real-world scenario is a bit more complicated because the model needs to take into consideration other features such as time of the day, and the input/outputs of each node, so I'm guessing it will need some reinforcement learning pipeline, but the task at any moment depends mostly on the algorithm for what I defined above, and it seems reasonably simple.
Is this problem tractable? And is there already any algorithm in literature to solve it? Because I haven't found one in my full workday of research.

Welcome to CV, Althis.  How does the cost depend on the path?  Would it, for instance, be a sum of costs along its edges? Or maybe it would involve costs at the nodes, or even depend on direction of travel along the edges?  We need you to tell us more about how you conceive of cost as depending on the paths.

Hi Whuber, the total cost of the path is just a sum of the cost for each edge taken. In the real-world scenario I am dealing with it is more complicated, as it involves also some stuff that goes on in the node, but for this minimal problem, let's consider it being just the sum of the cost of each edge taken.

That's a multiple (linear) regression problem, pure and simple.

This can be solved with linear regression (as a first-pass)
This problem can probably be handled as a linear regression (at least as a first pass analysis) using the total cost as the response variable and using explanatory variables that are counts of the number of times an edge is traversed in the path.  Suppose you have $m$ edges in your graph.  For a given path in your data, let $y$ denote the total cost and let $x_1,...,x_m$ denote the number of times each edge is traversed in a path.  For data points $i=1,...,n$ you can form the regression model:
$$y_i = \beta_0 + \sum_{i=1}^m \beta_i x_i + \varepsilon_i
\quad \quad \quad \quad \quad 
\varepsilon_i \sim \text{IID N}(0, \sigma^2).$$
In this model the parameter values $\beta_1,...,\beta_m$ represent the costs for travel on each edge and the parameter $\beta_0$ represents the fixed cost of travel (if any).  If you want to add additional covariates (e.g., time-of-day, etc.) then you can add additional explanatory variables and also consider whether these might induce interaction effects with your core explanatory variables.  In principle, all of this can be handled within linear regression analysis.
Please note that one assumption of the above model is that there is some random variation in costs that can go negative, so this would allow the total cost of a path (in a particular instance) to be less than the sum of the edge-costs.  If that is not allowed then you could vary the regression model to use an error term that has a distribution with strictly non-negative support (which adds some complexity but is still possible).
If you fit this model to your data using standard OLS methods you will get an estimate for your edge-costs.  Make sure you do diagnostic testing to see if the model is a reasonable fit to the data and make other checks on your model to see if it is reasonable.

Assume a simple weighted graph, where each edge has a cost and the cost of the path is a simple sum of costs of edges.
In this case we have the following matrix equation:
$$y_i=\sum_j X_{ij}\beta_j,$$
where $X_{ij}$ is number of times the edge $j$ is present in a path $i$, and $\beta_j$ is the cost of the path. The index $j$ enumerates all edges that are present in paths of our dataset.
If number of edges $j$ is greater than number of paths $i$ then there is no unique solution.
I would solve for $\beta$ using SVD (or Moore-Penrose pseudo inverse):
$$\beta=X^+y$$
You can apply OLS too to get the edge costs.
missing edges
If the edge was not used in any paths, then we can't estimate its cost. Unless, you have some kind of a model for costs of edges, e.g. near edges tend to have similar costs. You didn't provide any such hypothesis.
For instance, if we believe that the costs of similar in some sense edges are similar we could try to interpolate missing edge costs using estimated ones $\hat\beta_j$. You can create the dataset where each weight $\beta_j$ is an interpolation on other $\hat\beta_{k\ne j}$:
$$\hat\beta_j=\frac{e^{-d(k,j)/\theta}\hat\beta_k}{\sum_{k\ne j}e^{-d(k,j)/\theta}},$$
where $d(k,j)$ is a proximity (similarity) measure of $k$ to $j$ edge with a learned parameter $\theta$ (a scale), perhaps how far are the edges from each other either topologically in a graph.
Once we learned a scale $\theta$, we can apply the equation to estimate the cost of edges that were not present in the paths by interpolating them on estimated edges $\hat\beta_j$

Because in this model an edge is an explanatory variable, how could one possibly "spline the missing ones"?  Are you perhaps suggesting some kind of spatial model in which, say, the values of proximal edges are realizations of some underlying random process with non-zero covariance among nearby edges? If so, that ought to be incorporated in estimating all edge costs, not just the missing ones.

yes, I'm saying the only way to estimate all edges when only a subset of them is in the training dataset is when there's some kind of a pattern in edge costs, perhaps topological. and that we can extract the pattern from the observed edges. I suggested two step process, but you're right that it should be possible to do it in one step. perhaps, similar to how collaborative filtering works in recommendation engines where only a tiny subset of movie rating pairs (user, movie) is observed and the rest needs to be implied

I think you should remove the conjectures. In the problem, I suggested there is no way to estimate edges that don't show up in the path, and I think that is fine. I'm afraid your conjecture might confuse others more than it would help people in situations where the spatial conjecture is true.
